# DateTime.UtcNow from server response shows later time than DateTime.UtcNow called on the client after the response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I have a client application which calls a WEB API via REST. For administrative reasons I want to save the time of the corresponding steps, which looks something like this:

```
var requestStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
response = api.MakeSomeRequest();
serverEntryTime = response.ServerEntryTime;
var requestEndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

And the server side code looks something like this:

```
public MyDto MakeSomeRequest()
{
   var dto = new MyDto();
   dto.ServerEntryTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
   //Some action
   return dto;
}
```

Now, my problem is that when I check the timestamps, sometimes the `requestEndTime` shows an earlier time (only in milliseconds) than the `serverEntryTime`:

`serverEntryTime` = `2021-06-04 12:35:29.123`

`requestEndTime` = `2021-06-04 12:35:29.119`

The client and the server are on different machines but in the same timezone. Is it possible that the different DateTime structs on the different machines are operating with this kind of range of error? Or is there some other explanation?

Comment: computer clock can only be as accurate as the propagation delay between time servers and the computer. packet transmission times can vary. Plus, a lot of clients just won't have their time set correctly at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is generally expected to have small difference in the times of different machines. You should avoid using the times of the client machines (for consistency).

Comment: The NTP protocol should get most computers within 128ms. http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.2/ntpd.htm